# I am an admin in SSRS but do not have permission to change the subscription owner

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I can give people admin access to reports but when I try to change the SUBSCRIPTION OWNER I get the error

**The permissions granted to user 'NA\punkouter' are insufficient for performing this operation.**

Is there a way to get me the permissions I need to be able to change the SUBSCRIPTION OWNER setting in SSRS?

Comment: Do you have access to the default `Administrator` login?  That would probably be the best user for this sort of issue.

Comment: I manually updated the subscription owner from the database. It uses AD so I guess I would need the service account and log in to change it.. but anyways.. manually updated it fixed it